# Opencart Admin how to add Tabs into a module

Tags: php, html, opencart

I've created a module, but the admin side has become a bit of a beast, in order to file it a bit better I'd like to separate it with tabs (please see attached picture of "General", "Data" and "Design").

[admin tabs http://www.lumadec.co.uk/image/forum.jpg](http://www.lumadec.co.uk/image/forum.jpg)

I've added this code to my controller:

```
$this->data['tab_general'] = $this->language->get('tab_general');
$this->data['tab_data'] = $this->language->get('tab_data');
$this->data['tab_design'] = $this->language->get('tab_design');
```

and this code to my view folder:

```
<div id="tabs" class="htabs"><a href="#tab-general"><?php echo $tab_general; ?></a><a href="#tab-data"><?php echo $tab_data; ?></a><a href="#tab-design"><?php echo $tab_design; ?></a></div>
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form">
<div id="tab-general">
```

But this doesn't show anything in the module. Admittedly I have copied and pasted this from the "information" section of the admin panel, and I'm sure that I've missed something out, but if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Add following javascript code above `<?php echo $footer; ?>` code in bottom of the page.(in `.tpl` file)

```
$('#tabs a').tabs();
```

Comment: I had to move the HTML around a bit but this worked perfectly thanks for your help.